# Why are my wordpress links redirecting to old install?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

so I built a site on https://anthonymeszaros.com/philj/ and them manually moved the files and database to a new folder to work in https://anthonymeszaros.com/test3/. I changed the general links in the database.

for https://anthonymeszaros.com/test3/ hover over any menu links you'll see it's /test3/ as it should be but when you click it it redirects to /philj/ for some strange reason.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the following.

---

Update your `wp-config.php` file with these values.

```php
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' ); // Use your new URL
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' ); // Use your new URL
```

---

Also update your wp-options table in database. Search for `option_name` & `home` and update your site URL there.

You can read about the step by step proces here : https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214580498-How-do-I-change-the-WordPress-Site-URL-

---

Once you do that, go to `wp-admin/options-permalink.php` page and just hit save changes couple of time without any changes.

Comment: All I had to do was update my permalink twice for it to work, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Please check your .htaccess file, may be there write static url, or you have used any cache plugin you should clear all cache. also you should check wp-config.php file if you have added static directory.